# wxPython StatusBar temporary text

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, statusbar

How to properly set temporary text in statusbar, knowing that GUI operations need to take place in the main thread?

This is my current solution, using another thread

```
class StatusBar(wx.StatusBar):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(StatusBar, self).__init__(parent)

    def set_status(self, s, pause=None):
        if pause is None:
            self.SetStatusText(s)
        else:
            def aux():
                self.SetStatusText(s)
                time.sleep(pause)
                if self.GetStatusText() == s:
                    self.SetStatusText("")
            threading.Thread(target=aux).start()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a wx.Timer() object. You can set the timer to run for X number of milliseconds and then the event it is attached to will fire and you can clear the status bar's text and stop the timer too.

So you'd do something like this:

```
self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.clearStatus, self.timer)
self.timer.Start(10000)  # fire in 10 seconds
```

Then in your handler, you'd do something like this:

```
def clearStatus(self, event):
    self.SetStatusText("")
    self.timer.Stop()
```

You can read more at the following:

- http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/08/25/wxpython-using-wx-timers/
- http://wiki.wxpython.org/Timer

Comment: You can use `StartOnce` or pass `wxTIMER_ONE_SHOT` parameter to `Start` to make `Stop` call unnecessary as the timer will only fire once.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to check if the current status as the same as the one that was set (as the OP did in the question) before clearing it.